# Help With Following Windows Azure Toolkit iOS Example

Tags: ios, azure, toolkit

I am trying to follow the Getting Started with Windows Azure Toolkit for iOS example from Wade Wegener found [here](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/05/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios/).  I have followed the download links in the article but cannot find the files/folders that are referred to in the blog post e.g. libwatoolkitios.a, the device and simulator folders etc.  Maybe there is a problem with the downloads - I have tried both source and package downloads with no success.  Can someone point me in the right direction - or maybe supply the files that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that following the instructions in the Xcode 4.x (Git Submodule) section on [this page](https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-toolkit-ios#readme) was the answer - although I now have further problems that I will address in a separate question.